# The Request is not supported while trying to use Wincrypt RC4

Tags: c, windows, encryption

I am trying to use windows RC4 encryption from the Wincrypt library. This is the code that I have right now.

```
void main() {
    HCRYPTPROV hProv = 0;
    HCRYPTHASH hHash = 0;
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;

    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    if (!CryptCreateHash(hProv, CALG_RC4, 0, 0, &hHash)) {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
        return dwStatus;
    }

    return;
}
```

When running this, dwStatus is updated to `50` which means `The request is not supported.` This is happening on the `CryptCreateHash` function. If I change `CALG_RC4` to `CALG_MD5` it works, but I am after RC4.

I don't want to dig into Openssl and incorporate that or anything other than maybe a single or two files. Would like to just get this to work but I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: RC4 isn't a hash, it's a stream cipher.

Comment: yes, `CALG_RC4` invalid value for `CryptCreateHash`. use *CALG_MD5* or *CALG_SHA_xxx*. and better use Bcrypt api instead this legacy

Comment: I am using this because I found example that works. Which function would I use for RC4 instead of ```CryptCreateHash```

Comment: RC4 is not a hash, it is a cipher, as @Rup said.  Do you want a hash or a cipher?

Comment: Well if I am asking about RC4 then take a guess....

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, RC4 is a stream cipher used for bulk encoding, and not a hash function, hence the error code.
As cipher it can be used with the CryptEncrypt/CryptDecrypt functions.
You might still need a hash for preparation of the key though.
Overall use will be something similar to this sequence:

```
CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash);
CryptHashData(hHash, (BYTE*)str, strLength * sizeof(TCHAR), 0);
CryptDeriveKey(hCryptProv, CALG_RC4, hHash, s_KeyLength, &hKey);
CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, pBuff, &dwBuffSize, dwBuffSize);
```

(Error handling omitted)